# Accessing JS elements that loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, google-search

I'm trying to write a simple javascript to add more options to Google's search tools (the ones that are displayed when you press "More search tools". However, when I try to append the new element to an existing one, I receive an error. For example:

```
var yr = document.getElementById('qdr_y'); 
yr.parent.insertBefore(k,yr);
```

The second line throws an exception because `yr` is null. By examining the direct source code of a search results page, I've discovered that the basic results page contains only "All results", "More search tools", and the hidden "Less search tools". All the other options are injected in some other way.

How can I access these other elements so that I can add my new elements in the correct location?

Answer (score 1):

there you have it:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           TESTE
// @namespace      TESTE
// @description    TESTE
// @include        http*://*.google.*
// ==/UserScript==


var k = document.createElement('div');
k.innerHTML = "<center><b> bla bla </b></center>"
var yr = document.getElementById('gbmm'); 
yr.insertBefore(k,yr.firstChild);
```

(It is just an example. You shouldnt use `<center>` and `<b>` tags anymore).

[image]

Unless you mean something like this

[image]

Then the code should look like this

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           TESTE
// @namespace      TESTE
// @description    TESTE
// @include        http*://*.google.*
// ==/UserScript==

var k = document.createElement('li');
k.id = 'myoption'
k.className = 'tbou'
k.innerHTML = "<a href='http://userscripts.org/users/rasg' class='q qs'> Here is my option </a>"
var yr = document.getElementById('clir_1'); 
yr.parentNode.appendChild(k);
```

Also, consider adding JQuery to your GM scripts.

```
// @require        http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js
```

It is much easier to code.

*** EDIT ***

Based on your comment

> I'm looking to insert the node into the "All search tools" like in
>   your second solution. However, what you've posted is precisely what
>   I'm already doing, except with qdr_y instead of clir_1!

The following (very simple) code is the solution

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           TESTE 3
// @namespace      TESTE 3
// @description    TESTE 3
// @require        http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js
// @include        http*://www.google.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

$(window).load(function(){
    $('.tbpc').click()
    $('.tbt').on('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
        if ($('#my_li').length) { $('#my_li').show() }
        else { $('#whv_').parent().append("<li id='my_li' class='tbou' style=''><a class='q qs' href='http://userscipts.org'>Now i am inside</a>") }
    })
    $('.tbpo').on('click', function() { $('#my_li').hide() })
});
```

[image]

It is not as pretty as i would like to, but google make us do bad things :)

Comment: I'm looking to insert the node into the "All search tools" like in your second solution. However, what you've posted is precisely what I'm already doing, except with qdr_y instead of clir_1!

Comment: @skittleys ok. edited my answer and added a new code. now inside "All search tools"

Comment: This only works *one time* (and not always that depending on the circumstances).  Now try changing the search, AJAX overwrites the changes this script made.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for pointing my mistake. Fixed the code now. Now it monitors for changes and add the menu again if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `parent` in your code snippet should be `parentNode`.

Anyway, in general, for dynamic elements you need to check and wait for the target element(s).  And if something needs to be clicked, your script must click it. (It usually doesn't work well to try and use the pages JS functions on Google sites. Google pages are always extra "fun" to script for. ;) )

You need to make liberal use of polling to compensate for AJAX delays.  (Hooking into AJAX events or using mutation events both have a high pain-to-success ratio.  Polling works well.)

Finally, because it's Google, it's not enough to fire the poll once, because those search options are constantly getting overwritten.

Here's a sample script that works for me on US versions of Google search results (jQuery is required):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Google Search options add
// @include     http://www.google.com/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

if (window.top != window.self)  //-- Don't run on frames or iframes.
    return;

/*-- This script:
    1) Waits for the "More search tools" control.
    2) Clicks that control.
    3) Waits for the target element
    4) Adds our element before that one.
*/

waitForKeyElements ("#tbpi", clickMoreSearchToolsLink);

function clickMoreSearchToolsLink (jNode) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);

    waitForKeyElements ("#qdr_y", addOurExtraNodes);
}

function addOurExtraNodes (jNode) {
    jNode.before ("<li>Look at me, Ma!</li>");
}


/*--- waitForKeyElements():  A handy, utility function that
    does what it says.
*/
function waitForKeyElements (
    selectorTxt,    /* Required: The jQuery selector string that
                        specifies the desired element(s).
                    */
    actionFunction, /* Required: The code to run when elements are
                        found. It is passed a jNode to the matched
                        element.
                    */
    bWaitOnce,      /* Optional: If false, will continue to scan for
                        new elements even after the first match is
                        found.
                    */
    iframeSelector  /* Optional: If set, identifies the iframe to
                        search.
                    */
) {
    var targetNodes, btargetsFound;

    if (typeof iframeSelector == "undefined")
        targetNodes     = $(selectorTxt);
    else
        targetNodes     = $(iframeSelector).contents ()
                                           .find (selectorTxt);

    if (targetNodes  &&  targetNodes.length > 0) {
        /*--- Found target node(s).  Go through each and act if they
            are new.
        */
        targetNodes.each ( function () {
            var jThis        = $(this);
            var alreadyFound = jThis.data ('alreadyFound')  ||  false;

            if (!alreadyFound) {
                //--- Call the payload function.
                actionFunction (jThis);
                jThis.data ('alreadyFound', true);
            }
        } );
        btargetsFound   = true;
    }
    else {
        btargetsFound   = false;
    }

    //--- Get the timer-control variable for this selector.
    var controlObj      = waitForKeyElements.controlObj  ||  {};
    var controlKey      = selectorTxt.replace (/[^\w]/g, "_");
    var timeControl     = controlObj [controlKey];

    //--- Now set or clear the timer as appropriate.
    if (btargetsFound  &&  bWaitOnce  &&  timeControl) {
        //--- The only condition where we need to clear the timer.
        clearInterval (timeControl);
        delete controlObj [controlKey]
    }
    else {
        //--- Set a timer, if needed.
        if ( ! timeControl) {
            timeControl = setInterval ( function () {
                    waitForKeyElements (    selectorTxt,
                                            actionFunction,
                                            bWaitOnce,
                                            iframeSelector
                                        );
                },
                200
            );
            controlObj [controlKey] = timeControl;
        }
    }
    waitForKeyElements.controlObj   = controlObj;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks like it will work! I don't have time right now, but I'll try implementing it later to ensure that it works.   However, is it actually necessary to "click" on the "More search tools" button?

Comment: Note that the user is not clicking, the script is.  Because Google's JS is ever shifting, and uses changing "salt-like" constants, having the script click really is the simplest, most robust way.

Comment: Worked fine for me when I tested it. Please link to the exact page that triggered the problem.  The script doesn't have any way of duplicating "All results"; are you sure something else isn't going on? Another script running?